# How to disable shadows in Eevee - Blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

How to disable shadows in Eevee (completely or of certain objects)?

Answer (score 6):

Shadows can be disabled for each light in the `Object Data` section of the settings of the respective light:

[image: Disabling shadows in the light settings]

(This is only a partial answer, as it doesn't state how to disable for certain objects only.)

Answer (score 1):

Properties Editor > Render Tab > Select Eevee Render Engine

Properties Editor > Material Tab > Settings Drop-Down > Shadow Mode > Select None